# Ajax post call should return to html page

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, rest

I am calling a POST method from ajax and want it to return the html page with all attributes.

Mycode:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postMethod", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public String getPage( @RequestBody(required=false) Object obj, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

    request.getSession().setAttribute("sess", cmp);
    model.addAttribute("one", list);
    model.addAttribute("two", list2);
    model.addAttribute("object", new object());
    return "htmlpage";
}
```

Ajax call:

```
var dataTosend = prepareDataToSend(data);
    $.ajax({
        url : getContextPath()
        + "/app/postMethod",
        type : 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify(dataTosend),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //return to htmlpage
        },
        error : function() {

        }
    });
```

Myhtml sample:
it is not a form:

```
<div id="page">
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <div id="header" class="inside content-wrapper">
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
  <div id="main-content">
    <div class="content">
      <!-- accounts -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label style="margin: 0 0 20px 0">Account</label>
          </td>
          <td> &nbsp; </td>
          <td>
            <select id="Dropdown" onchange="onDropdown()">
              <option th:each="type : ${list}" th:value="${type.Id}" th:text="${type.Name}"></option>
            </select> &nbsp; &nbsp;
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          <!..............more div and other html data...........>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I do a get call to the method, it will returning to html page but while post call page not redirect, I want to redirect to htmlpage.html with all the attributed set in post, any solution is welcome.

Comment: I page is rendering by using $().html(response) but other functionality is not working as scripts are not loaded and url also not changed. Still search more

Comment: What exactly you need? reload whole page with new attributes? or just change the elements?

Comment: reload entire page with new attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for you comments.
As I want to reload entire page, I am redirecting to the same page on success as it is GET and POST both:

```
var dataTosend = prepareDataToSend(data);
    $.ajax({
        url : getContextPath()
        + "/app/postMethod",
        type : 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify(dataTosend),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
           window.location.replace(getContextPath()+"/app/postMethod");
        },
        error : function() {

        }
    });
```

It's working fine in my case.